# Schedule a google sheet script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, conditional-operator

I need to create a script to run every hour only between working hours (say 9 am to 5 pm) between Monday to Friday. I scheduled the trigger to run the script every hour, however such scheduling does not allow to limit the script running within working hours of Monday to Friday, so I want to build the scheduling function within the script. I am trying below script, but that not working:

```
function Auto_Update() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
if {
  1<Weekday(NOW())<7 {
    if {
      8<text(now(),"hh") <18 

<<My script>>

}
}
}
};
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weekday() and Now() are google Sheet functions. You need JavaScript functions to manipulate dates. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp) for more.

To check if the value of variable is in a range, you need to use the `&&` (and) operator. Something like this:

```
function Auto_Update() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var today = new Date();
  var dayOfWeek = today.getDay();
  var hourOfDay = today.getHours();  
  if(dayOfWeek > 0 && dayOfWeek < 7 && hourOfDay > 8 && dayOfWeek < 18) {
    //your script here
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ADW.